# Mysql Join on an Update query?

Tags: php, mysql

Is Join works with Mysql UPDATE Query? I want to copy the values of a field to another table. This two tables linked with id. Something like

```
Update table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t2.t1id=t1.id set t2.amt=t1.amt;
```

Is this correct? Any other Solution? Can we use Phpmyadmin to achieve this?

Comment: I am applying this on a mission critical table set. That is why asked like this. Thanks for your Confirmation. Great Worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do a join in an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE table1 t1, table2 t2 SET t2.amt=t1.amt WHERE t2.t1id=t1.id
```

More in [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html).

Comment: Thanks T.J. for the update... it makes it more understandable